# Limite para a função strtotime em php

Tags: php, cakephp, data, strtotime

Estou usando a função strtotime conforme exemplo abaixo, com o cakephp.
ao passar a soma de 50 anos esta retornando null, o máximo que consigo retornar é somando 20 anos.

Alguém saberia se isso é limitação/configuração do cakephp ou do próprio php?

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+50years'));
```

Comment: Tenho a pequena impressão que isso já tenha sido respondido. Não há nenhum problema em a pergunta ser duplicada, mas é importante já demonstrar aqui o conteúdo existente no site :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo a documentação o limite da função [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) é `19/01/2038`, pois o PHP utilizar um integer de 32 bits para fazer a representação dessa data.

Para contornar o problema utiliza a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), no exemplo abaixo foi adicionado um período de 50 anos(`P50Y`).

```
$data = new DateTime();
$data->add(new DateInterval('P50Y'));
echo $data->format('d/m/Y'); //25/01/2066
```

Comment: Eu ia perguntar se seria melhor usar o datetime kk sabe se ha algum limite para ele? +1

Comment: @lvcs lembra do bug do ano 2000? existe outro, bug de 2038.

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno rray.